# How to change json string to LinkedList when using fastjson in Java?

Tags: java, json, fastjson

I want to change the string into LinkedList,I write the code but it happen in to a exception,`java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedList`,How to fix it?

```
LinkedList<String> names=new LinkedList<String>();
    names.add("a");
    names.add("b");
    String str=JSON.toJSONString(names);
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println((LinkedList<String>)JSON.parseArray(str,String.class));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast an `ArrayList` to a `LinkedList` so you have to create a `LinkedList`. Try `new LinkedList<String>(JSON.parseArray(str, String.class))`. This creates a LinkedList containing all the elements of the JSON array. If the list does not have to be exactly a `LinkedList`, you can also try just using the `List` interface.